# Storing data in proper OOP way

Tags: java, swing, oop

Currently I've wrote a program which allows user to add data to JTable, save JTable content to txt file and load data from file. My txt data file looks like:

```
 Apple;Food;50
 ####
 Vibrador;Electronics;125
 ####
```

I would like to add timestamp for further search option and I though that filtering data by iterating whole file and selecting every 4th item (for example) would not be an efficient way of doing that ( I could separate 1 column per 1 file, but wait a minute... OOP?). So my question is how to implement my data in OOP way?

[Save file method and screenshot of jFrame](http://pastebin.com/L1r9zfwtiv.pl/images/94501963022122177163.png)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What the heck are you trying to ask? And your link does not work for me.

Comment: Not sure at all what you are asking

Comment: Let's see some code!

Comment: This is whole program. pastebin.com/NfykvTnz

And I'm asking how to store data not in txt file but in class for example. How to store data in OOP way. Not to take all cells in row and store them as a strings but like and objects.

Comment: Are you looking for database software such as mySQL?

Comment: @kirbyquerby no, this program have to be offline. I know how to use databases, and I know it may sounds werid.

Comment: You use variables to store data in a class

Comment: There are any number of ways you could store the data, text file, sql or graph database, xml. The method by which you process the data is another issues, you could generate an index of the file making easier and quicker to search, use xpath for xml files or sql for database files

Comment: From an oop point of view, your data would objects, you'd have some kind of factory that would filter/process the data and return a list of the data objects

Comment: Please post all code here with your question and not in a link. Links are not helpful for future visitors, and are not accessible to all current visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a model class for your records:

### Model Class

```
class Record
{
   private String item;
   private String category;
   private int quantity; 
   private String timestamp

   // constructor
   public Record (String item, String category, int quantity, String timestamp)
   {
       this.item = item;
       // assign rest of members...
   }

   public String getCategory ()
   {
       return category;
   }

   // rest of getters and setters for all members...
}
```

Next, have a parser class that reads the txt file and creates a List of Record objects. Your parser could return such a list:

```
List<Record> records = new ArrayList<Records>();
```

### Searching

When you want to search your data just iterate through the list and gather the matches. For example, if you want to find all items in the "**Food**" category, you could do something like this:

```
String searchCategory = "food";
List<Record> matches = new ArrayList<Records>();

for (Record r : records)
{
    String currentCategory = r.getCategory();

    // this will do case-insensitive matches
    if (currentCategory.equalsIgnoreCase(searchCategory))
    {
        matches.add(r);
    }
}
```